# Rails content_tag vs tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference between `content_tag` and `tag` in Rails? From what I've read, it seems that `content_tag` requires content to be passed to it.

Why does this matter? What's different syntactically, as well as what cases would I use one vs the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically `tag` makes an *empty* tag and `content_tag` is used for building, well tags with some content.

say you use `tag` to build `IMG` tags and use `content_tag` for building `DIV`s

Answer (score 12):

In recent versions of Rails, the difference between both is largely blurred, for [`tag` now also supports blocks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag).